# How to return default error if observable next is undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, rxjs, redux-observable

I made a network request and I got some response. I would like to return default error each time I find out that response value is undefined. And I may have multiple levels of objects inside response value.

How can I replace **if else** block from code below with some **rxjs** operator.

```
import { ofType } from "redux-observable"
import { from } from "rxjs"

export const savePostEpic = (action$: any) => action$.pipe(
    ofType(Types.NewPost),
    mergeMap((action: NewPostAction) => {
        const { input } = action
        return from(somePromise(input) as Promise<MyResult>)
            .pipe(
                map(response => response.data),
                if (response.data === 'undefined') {
                    return { type: Types.Error, message: 'response is undefined' }
                } else {
                    if (response.data.createPost === 'undefined') {
                        return { type: Types.Error, message: 'response is undefined' }
                    } else {
                        return { type: Types.Post, post: reponse.data.createPost }
                    }
                }
        )
    })
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get is https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/defaultIfEmpty
IMHO you just need to do some good refactoring and it's sufficient enough to reduce a lot of code

```
map(response=>(response.data === 'undefined' || response.data.createPost === 'undefined')?
{ type: Types.Error, message: 'response is undefined'}:{ type: Types.Post, post: reponse.data.createPost }
)
```

--- defaultIfEmpty usage ---

```
pipe(
filter(response=>response.data&&response.data.createPost),
map(response=>({ type: Types.Post, post: reponse.data.createPost })),
defaultIfEmpty({ type: Types.Error, message: 'response is undefined'}),
)
```

Comment: How would I get empty if I filter out all undefined. Nothing will be passed down the stream.

Comment: I am currently refactoring & it will get shorter with introduction of optional chaining in typescript beta. e.g. response?.data?createPost. I am more interested in Rx solution.

Comment: defaultIfEmpty works in a way that if the source stream doesn't emit any but completed, it will skip other operator and jump to defaultIfEmpty. as for your second question, there's no such support right now.

Comment: I tried it out and Typescript is saying {type: Types.Post, post: any} is not matching { type: Types.Error, message: string }

Comment: It worked when I set defaultIfEmpty({ type: Types.Post, post: { id: '', title: '' }})

Comment: You probably got to set some (or ||) typing from source

Comment: Optional chaining feature is public now. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining